# Adding of time in Excel gives a strange answer

Tags: microsoft-excel

I tried to add the following times:

```
4:28:31
```

and

```
17:51:13
```

and got:

```
46:19:44
```

using simply **=firstCell+secondcell**

all are in **[h]:mm:ss format.**

What could be the reason why the answer is wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get 22:19:44. Check your data types.

Comment: Notice the only one [hours]:mm:ss in your format - you need hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 1):

try that one....

Enter your hours and minutes in the following format:

```
hh:mm            example         10:20        for 10 hours, 20 minutes, OR 
hh:mm:ss        example        10:20:32     for 10 hours, 20 minutes, 32 seconds
```

In excel's mind:

12 hours + 13 hours = 25 hours (in yours too?)

However it will display to you as:

12 hours + 13 hours = 1 hour (it rolls over to the next day to show a time-of-day format)

To see the correct total of hours:

**Method A**

Right Click on your total
Click on Format Cells
On the Number Tab, under "custom" change your settings to [h]:mm

**Method B**

Right Click on your total
Click on Format Cells
On the Number Tab, Select "Number" and 2 Decimal Places
In your formula bar, add *24 to the end of the sum formula    `(example =SUM(A20:G20)*24 )`

difference between Method A and Method B is

In Method A, eight and a half hours will appear as 8:30
In Method B, eight and a half hours will appear as 8.50

Answer (score 0):

If you format your cells in **hh:mm:ss** you get the correct result:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but what is the difference?

Comment: problem: with hh:mm:ss, I reach a 24hr limit. if I sum say 4:00:00 and 23:00:00 i do not get 27:00:00 but 3:00:00 (subtract 24hrs). how do i make it the true sum?

Comment: You meant the formate would be "[h]:mm:ss" that is why I've said "If you format your cells in hh:mm:ss" ...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem was hidden information.

[image]

One of the times was actually the time shown plus a day.  The time containing the extra day was formatted hh:mm:ss, so only the portion less than a day was displayed.

Comment: I've successfully produced correct answer since all 3 cells are formatted as `[H]:mm:ss`,, `22:19:44`.